# Rest API : function query

Tags: api, rest, url

I'm building a rest API.

```
GET /areas/
```

...gives areas.

Now, I want to have every areas crossing a circle. Is this OK or ugly ?

```
GET /areas/circle((1,1),5)
```

In other word, how should I write a route for a function. It's a question about readability, usability and best practices. Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in the arguments as GET parameters,  now all you have to think about is how to represent those. 
For example:

```
GET /areas/circle?x=1&y=1&r=5
GET /areas/circle?c=1,1&r=5
```

It's a tradeoff between taste and ease I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use something like this:

```
/areas/circle?a=1&b=1&c=5
```

or

```
/areas/circle?a=1,1&b=5
```

I'm not sure about the relationship between areas & circle. If there is a hierarcical relationship, topmost one should come first in your route structure.